# Add Expires or Cache Control Header to static content in IIS

Tags: .net, http, iis, caching

After running the [YSlow plugin](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow) on a site, I saw that one of the [recommendations](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) was to add far future expires headers to the scripts, stylesheets, and images.

I would like to do this, does anyone have experience with this?  I am using IIS 7 and I read an [article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247404) but am not interested in disabling caching for asp pages or images, I actually want to force caching for static content.  Also, the ideal situation would not exist in code, but in the web server configuration.

So, what steps would I have to take to have every image, javascript file, and stylesheet to be cached?

Comment: for ASP.NET Core, see [Change the headers of static files in Asp.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256244/change-the-headers-of-static-files-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 8):

> Can this be done in IIS 6?

To configure content expiration

1. In the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager administrative tool, right-click Your Web Site, and then click Properties.
2. In the Properties dialog box, on the HTTP Headers tab specify expiration time, and then click OK.

Comment: Does this affect only static content such as images / style sheets? I don't want IIS to tell the browser to cache aspx pages that get updated frequently.

Answer (score 6):

I added a custom header on the http headers tab instead of checking the box, because I could not include "public" in the Cache Control header otherwise.

I did this for folders with static content such as /images/, /scripts/, /css/ and a few others, not the whole project.

Name:
Cache-Control
Value:
public, max-age=604800

VR