# Disable Caching For A Single JS File Using Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I currently cache everything possible on my site (images, JS, CSS). There is only one JS file that I need to be loaded fresh every single time. How do I omit just one file from caching, using web.config, whilst leaving everything else cached?

Note that I tried another link here, and it didn't seem to stop the caching of my file:
[How do I disable caching of an individual file in IIS 7 using weserver config settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929284/how-do-i-disable-caching-of-an-individual-file-in-iis-7-using-weserver-config-set)

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="path/to/the/file.js">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

(Note that the path is relative to the web.config file)

Comment: IE's cache is pretty annoying during development. I put the `DisableCache` in `Web.Debug.config` and it works fine. Thx!

Comment: It definitely /can/ work - what caching headers are you seeing going across the network?

Comment: It can be added without '<location>' tags, so it is applied to whole project

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it using web.config, but you could add a unique querystring parameter to the javascript url in order for it to be loaded every time:

If you are using ASP.NET

```
<script src="mycode.js?<%=System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()%>"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the path for it not as a static URL but get an ASPX page to serve the script. Inside your ASPX page just send back the text:

```
byte[] javascriptTextBuffer = GetMyJavascript();
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
Response.Write(javascriptTextBuffer);
```

*Inside the page [turn off caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache).*

Having said that, it seems to me that you are doing something wrong that have to load the JavaScript file everytime. **Make scripts static but use parameters to drive versatility.**

Comment: I agree...if you need certain js data to be fesh everytime, it seems like you would be better served by having a a few dynamic elements defined in your page that your static scripts can use.

Comment: Hmmmm... That will work, but is not ideal for many reasons. Hopefully a better solution exists :-).

Comment: The reason that the JS isn't to be cached is that it's a plugin that goes onto a customer website. I would obviously like to be able to update that plugin and have it run the latest 'stuff' on that customer website.

Comment: So you are explicitly making customer's site less performant for your convinience? Unless you are creating virus I'd recommned to have cahing set to some time (i.e. a day is likley enough to reduce performance impact and provide reasonably lates version of your script).