# How to prevent browser cache for some files only in ASP.Net 5?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, asp.net-core

In the previous version I would do this like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929284/how-do-i-disable-caching-of-an-individual-file-in-iis-7-using-weserver-config-se). But in new version of ASP there is no web.config file, and I believe it should be done in launchSettings.json file.

Basically what I want to do it stop caching app.js file and all .html files from templates folder. How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you're still free to add `<meta`> tags in your HTML pages for each page you don't want to cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Also note that if you're deploying to IIS then you still have a `wwwroot` (or what you specified in `project.json`) where you can put a `web.config` files (parsed by IIS).

If you want to do it with configuration then add a `Configure()` method in your `Startup` class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        await next();
    });

    // ...
}
```

Note that if you want to apply that HTTP header only to certain pages you just need to check `PathString` property of `HttpRequest` (`Request` property of `HttpContext`) or if you need it for every static file (same as above if you want to apply to only some of them) using:

```
application.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }
};
```

Which headers you should send to be compatible with browsers you need to support has been discussed on [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49547/1207195).

Comment: I've tried the one with the Configure, it works with Chrome,  but not in IE. Have too clear cache manually to see changes

Comment: That's another widely discussed problem. A comprehensive post here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/49547/1207195

Comment: @Whistler: Try to use `context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0")` instead of `context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269567/315935)). It should work in all cases inclusive proxy.

Comment: @Whistler: Try to use `context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "private, no-store")` instead of `context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`

Answer (score 4):

If you are a PWA developer in .Net Core or you are a react or angular you can use the following code to cache all static files except the service worker or your main app.js. Thumbs up if it helps you:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //...
            //One year 31536000
            string cachePeriod = env.IsDevelopment() ? "600" : "31536000";
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{ OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {

                if (ctx.File.Name == "sw.js")
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, no-cache");
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cachePeriod}");
                }
            } });
    //...    
}
```