# How should I store static data for a Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an image model and with it are a set of sizes that the image can be resized to that consist of a string name and the max height/width for that size.

My initial thought was to put it in the database and create a model for image sizes, but this seems like overkill and this would be called fairly often and not changed very often.

So I thought I could store it as a form of static data (a list of an ImageSize class or something), but I'm not sure where in the Controller to put this.

Where should I put this data?

Answer (score 3):

You could create another class holding your static data then add the using statement in your Controller class to read the data inside of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `web.config` file for storing static data. You can also use `xml file` or `application` variables for this purpose.

But I would have preferred the `web.config` file.

More details

[IIS and Static content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211992/iis-and-static-content)