# Aurelia bundling and production deployment on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, aurelia, dev-to-production

I am new to Aurelia. I am able to run the Aurelia app using 'gulp watch' in local system. Now I want to put the Aurelia app in an external server which has NodeJS installed. 
I used 'gulp bundle' to create dist folder entries. What are the next steps in deploying after bundling? Aurelia official documentation doesn't explain after bundling steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Aurelia documentation stops here is because this is as far as Aurelia goes. Aurelia is a framework for building applications. You will need a resource for hosting applications at this point.

If your application consists exclusively of your Aurelia application--that is, if you have no server behind it, you might consider static file hosting, since Aurelia files are static javascript files. Here are some resources you might find helpful.

Note that you do **not** want to use `gulp watch` in a production environment. The default `gulp watch` command leverages a node-based development server (browser-sync at the time of writing) which that both slows down your server and adds unwanted behavior.

**IIS (Windows Server)**

- [IIS and Static
  Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211992/iis-and-static-content)
- [How to Install IIS 7 and Setup a Static Website in 13 Easy
  Steps](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/windows-server-2008-iis7)

**nginx (Linux server)**

- [Serving Static Content](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/)

**node-based (any server)**

- [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http)
- [Serving static files in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: please upvote and accept if you find this helpful, and then do it again because we're friends.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `gulp export` then copy and paste the export folder to the server.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. Where do I put the code in NodeJS server so that I don't have to do 'gulp watch' every time my putty session expires?