# Control Caching in IIS7 from C#

Tags: c#, iis, caching, iis-7

I have situation described bellow: 
In CMS was implemented two presentation server  which aren't on same machine. Client want to enable IIS caching only on one machine, but changing manually web.config isn't suggested. So I am planning to make some C# code which will make changes in web.config in order to ensure proper cache settings.  Is it possible  or exist any other solution ( change other settings, edit other files...) for the problem?

Comment: I think you should read what you just wrote and write it again... its hard to understand what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

"You can configure the  element at the server level in the ApplicationHost.config file or at the site, application, or at the directory level in a Web.config file."

If you have physical access to the server you can run from the console appcmd.exe:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/caching /+"profiles.[extension='asp',policy='CacheUntilChange',kernelCachePolicy='CacheUntilChange']" /commit:apphost
```

Check this link: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching

**EDITED**

The first answer to this question says how to configure caching at folder level, the 2nd answer for file level:

[How to configure static content cache per folder and extension in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7)

If you didn't specify any caching rules at file or folder level, disabling global caching should do it.

Comment: Is it enough to disable caching only in IIS Output Cache or I must disable it in all website and folder inside IIS.