# How to cache js and css files of ASP.NET MVC application served on IIS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

On our `IIS Server 7.5` there are several `ASP.NET MVC` applications and in order to increase performance, we want to cache static contents (`javascript`, `css`, etc.). I have look Static Content Caching on [Microsoft IIS and ASP.NET MVC caching techniques](http://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2015/april/microsoft-iis-and-aspnet-mvc-caching-techniques/) but not sure if it will fullfill my requirements. So, what is the best option for making `IIS Server` cache static content on `MVC` project side **programmatically**?

Comment: In what way are you wanting to cache them? Client browsers will take care of caching static content as and when needed.

Comment: Actually I think of using Static content caching as explained on [Microsoft IIS and ASP.NET MVC caching techniques](http://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2015/april/microsoft-iis-and-aspnet-mvc-caching-techniques/) and [Caching versioned static files with ASP.NET MVC and IIS7](http://aboutcode.net/2011/03/21/caching-versioned-static-files-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis7.html).

Comment: At there, the cache mechanism is made on IIS side and I need a solution which will work after the client clear browse's cache. So, Static content caching seem to be good, but I have no idea what if I update a js or css file and deploy my application if I had selected 360 days?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following configuration in asp.net mvc applications to cache static content, enable gzip compression, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- GZip static file content.  Overrides the server default which only compresses static files over 2700 bytes -->
        <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\websites\_compressed" minFileSizeForComp="1024">
            <scheme dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" name="gzip"/>
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*" />
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" />
                <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
                <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" />
                <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true"/>
        <staticContent>
            <!-- Set expire headers to 30 days for static content-->
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".html"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".css"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".js"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".map"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".map" mimeType="application/json"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".rss"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".xml"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <!-- HTML5 Audio/Video mime types-->
            <remove fileExtension=".mp3"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".mp4"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".ogg"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".ogv"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".webm"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
            <!-- Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad -->
            <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".svgz"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
            <!-- HTML4 Web font mime types -->
            <!-- Remove default IIS mime type for .eot which is application/octet-stream -->
            <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".ttc"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".crx"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".xpi"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".safariextz"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
            <!-- Flash Video mime types-->
            <remove fileExtension=".flv"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".f4v"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
            <!-- Assorted types -->
            <remove fileExtension=".ico"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".webp"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".htc"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".vcf"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".torrent"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".cur"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".webapp"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```