# Leverage browser caching for images in mvc using c#

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I am using clientCache in my web.config:

```
<staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00"/>
</staticContent>
```

and in the controller on action I am using the OutputCache attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300)] // 300 for 5 mins
```

The problem is I am getting the error in google speed insight:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can leverage browser caching for images in mvc?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696885/1093508

Comment: @ Dávid Molnár thanks for share the link but my images are dynamic not static

Comment: Can you add some sample code how do you generate the images and the output (HTTP headers)?

Comment: <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      </customHeaders>         <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>                                                                                      and in my controller it looks like                                                                                     [OutputCache(Duration = 300)]
        public ActionResult home()

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?