# Trying to Programmatically Expire the HTTP Response Headers

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, http-headers, wmi, cache-expiration

Our Team is building a C# project with a Silverlight module. We deploy to a Windows 2008 with IIS 7. I’m trying to Programmatically Expire the HTTP Response Headers Associated with a Folder called ClientBin immediately. I know how to do it manually through IIS Manager. ( Basically, I go to the HTTP Response Headers Section of the folder or file that is of interest, and then I use "Set Common Headers...." to expire immediately.) However, we will be Redeploying to IIS a number of times, and I want to ensure that it is programmatically done because it’s a headache to keep Reconfiguring all the time.

Should I do it from the C# code of my project or is it better practice to do it using WMI scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kev and @jeff-cuscutis have provided the ways to configure expiration of the HTTP Response Headers using XML configuration in the web.config file of a ASP.NET application

[How to configure static content cache per folder and extension in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7)

ou can set specific cache-headers for a whole folder in either your root web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

<!-- Note the use of the 'location' tag to specify which 

   folder this applies to-->

<location path="images">

<system.webServer>

  <staticContent>

    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:15" />

  </staticContent>

</system.webServer>

</location>

</configuration>
```

Or you can specify these in a web.config file in the content folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

<system.webServer>

<staticContent>

  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:15" />

</staticContent>

</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I'm not aware of a built in mechanism to target specific file types.

You can do it on a per file basis. Use the path attribute to include the filename

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

<location path="YourFileNameHere.xml">

    <system.webServer>

        <staticContent>

            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />

        </staticContent>

    </system.webServer>

</location>

</configuration>
```