# SQL cache dependency: Poll specific time of day

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

We want to improve the performance of our WCF service by introducing output caching.

For each different URL (`varyByParam="none" varyByCustom="RawUrl"`) we want to cache the result as long as the database table FooBar has not changed.

However, we want to check such a change only once per day (6:20 AM). If the table changes during the day, we do not want the cache to be cleared until the next day 6:20 AM.

We know that this can result in unconsistent outputs, however, in our application scenario this is not a problem.

How to tell the outputCache to check for changes only at 6:20 AM each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Response.Cache.SetExpires` method as descrived in [How to: Cache Versions of a Page Using Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y96218s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The code will be something like:

```
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(new DateTime(tomorrow.Year, tomorrow.Month, tomorrow.Day, 6, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("RawUrl")
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply: Is this also possible to set in the Web.config configuration file?

Comment: @D.R. In general answer is "yes, it is possible to configure client caching using web.config" (look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7), but I cannot see how to implement the `check for changes only at 6:20 AM each day` using web.config. As alternative, you can create a static class that will have a method with `Cache` input parameter and in that method you can centralize caching configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Set your IIS Application Pool to reset at 6:20am every day, instead of making this a code solution.

Some browsers will ignore the HTTP Cache headers as suggested above.