# Creating an embedded image button in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, imagebutton

I need to create a button in ASP.net that I can embed into another web page.

Essentially the button will query a DB server side on page load and then change it's image depending on the return of the query.

Does anyone know the best approach for this? I am not a pro at ASP.net as you can tell. Written in C# preferably.

Comment: Not really sure where to start. I just want to figure out how to make a simple view that is only a button. I can do the coding for sure... but I can't for the life of me get a template going that is just the button so I can click on it and write the db connection server side + all the other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest using a `IHttpHandler` instead of a generic WebForm. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler(v=vs.110).aspx

The handler is more suitable for this request as it will be able to respond quickly and is purpose built for handling specific requests that are not necessarily HTML based. This can be quite simple to wire up to accept a request, query the database and generate an image that you choose. Now you haven't provided much information about where the image comes from but lets look at a simple request.

To begin in a webforms web application select a new `GenericHandler` which we will name `DynamicImage.ashx`. Which will build our initial template as below.

```
public class DynamicImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This template provides the basics to handle our request. When the request arrives the WebServer will execute the `ProcessRequest()` method passing in the `HttpContext` as a parameter. From here we can use this to deliver our response.

For argument sakes lets say we are querying the image based on the `QueryString` parameter `username` which represents a user in our database. I have included some basic code on your steps to achieve this. (Code commented)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //get our username from the query string
    var username = context.Request.QueryString["username"];

    //clear the response and set the content type headers
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

    //if the username is empty then end the response with a 401 not found status code
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        context.Response.End();
        return;
    }

    //do a db query to validate the user. If not valid do a 401 not found
    bool isValidUser = new UserManager().IsValidUser(username);
    if (!isValidUser)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        context.Response.End();
        return;
    }

    //get the user image file path from a server directory. If not found end with 401 not found
    string filePath = context.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/App_Data/userimages/{0}.png", username));
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        context.Response.End();
        return;
    }

    //finish the response by transmitting the file
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

To call this handler you can simply set the `src` of the image to a path similar to `/DynamicImage.ashx?username=johndoe`.

Now your requirement may be slightly different. For example you may be retrieving the image from the database as a `byte[]` therefore instead of using the `context.Response.TransmitFile()` method you may wish to use the `context.Response.BinaryWrite()` method. This method transmits a `byte[]` as the response stream.

Finally I would refer you to another post (of mine) that talks about caching these images from a client perspective. This is very helpful if your button will be generated quite frequently. [Leverage browser caching in IIS (google pagespeed issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074198/leverage-browser-caching-in-iis-google-pagespeed-issue/21270716#21270716)

Comment: I believe this solution will work. Essentially the state it is querying is a "yes" or "no" state for availability. If it is yes one image is shown, if it is no another image is shown.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something as simple as

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/arrow-down.gif" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

and code behind:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // do some DB processing here
    ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/arrow-up.gif";
}
```

If I understand what you are asking.

To put it under the page load would look something like:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // perform db processing here
        ImageButton.ImageUrl = "~/arrow-up.gif";
    }
}
```

is all that is needed. Setting the ImageUrl line can be put wherever you need it.

Comment: i need the DB processing on page load... to change the button image.

Comment: @willxj: just change the click event to pageload event. also wrap it inside `!IsPostBack`

Comment: naveen is right. It is a simple matter of putting that line where you need it. I've updated the answer accordingly.