# "Leverage browser caching" not working in IIS or Page Speed reporting wrong

Tags: caching, iis-7.5

I have tried set  this in web.config:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

I also modified the value through the GUI but my `Response Headers` still says `no-cache`:
[image]

I read several posts and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074198/leverage-browser-caching-in-iis-google-pagespeed-issue) looked promising but still I can't get it to work.

From what I understand from this image the image `bbb.png` is taken from the cache but `Page Speed` (after refresh, and after waiting a couple of minutes) that it still is not being cashed:
[image]

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You're not reading it correctly. The **Request** header says "no-cache" but the **Response** header is correct. I'll agree it is silly that Chrome puts the Response before the Request, though.

Comment: I might have read wrong but under Google `Page Speed` this image (and the rest of the images) still appears. The image is taken through a link from one of our sub sites, does that matter?

Comment: To clarify: The sub site has the same setting and it has the `cacheControlMaxAge`set to 1800 seconds which is 30 minutes. So that number is correct. However, it's still not caching anyting.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://varvy.com/pagespeed/ I'm not caching 3rd party images:
[image]