# How to fix Leverage Browser Caching issue on google insights using MVC .Net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm unable to fix Leverage Browser Caching issue on Google PageSpeed Insight, by the way, I'm using this code in `Web.config` file but not fixed yet

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMaxAge="12:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
</staticContent>
```

It's just showing 12 hours as in below image but not fixed yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this Google PageSpeed site inform you about issue? You should put more than 24 hours for errors to dissapear.

Please refer to this my [question about laverage browser caching in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074198/leverage-browser-caching-in-iis-google-pagespeed-issue). I'm sure it will help you.

Comment: Yes on Google PageSpeed showing Leverage Browser Caching issue

Comment: You should put more than 24 hours if they didn't change limit for issues to dissapear

Comment: By the way how much normal time should be?

Comment: I don't think there is unique answer. It depends. I cached static content for 24 hours if I remember correctly.