# ASP.NET "one time cache" for file

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to implement what I'd call a "one time cache" for specific files in my ASP.NET 3.5 site.  Upon request, the file is downloaded from a remote file server onto the web server, then served up by my page.  The problem arises when I go to delete it.  If I delete the file in the `OnUnload` method, the client doesn't have time to retrieve it.  Is there some way of detecting the download of a file and deleting it immediately after it is first accessed?  My code is like this:

```
    private bool _deleteFlag = false;
    private string _deleteFile = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["file"])) {
            _deleteFlag = Request.QueryString["file"].Contains(@"cache/");
            _deleteFile = Request.QueryString["file"];
        }
    }

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e) {
        if (_deleteFlag) {
            // Can't delete here; the client is still trying to retrieve it.
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(_deleteFile));
        }
        base.OnUnload(e);
    }
```

I'm leaning towards writing an `IHttpHandler` that overrides the file request, but that feels like overkill.

Comment: If you have access to IIS you can try this [SO link][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7

Comment: @karthick, This looks promising.  But will it cause IIS *delete* my files, or do I need to devise a mechanism for that myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

When you add your file, insert it into the `HttpRuntimeCache` and set the Key to the `FileName` and set the TimeOut to say 10 seconds.  Then on the CacheItemRemoved callback, delete the file.  It's not exact, but it should roughly meet your use case.

```
public static object LoadFile()
{
    var filename = ParseFileNameFromHttpRequest();

    var a = loadFileSomeHow(filename);

    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
        filename ,
        a, 
        null,
        System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
        new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0,10,0,0),
        CacheItemPriority.Default,
        new CacheItemRemovedCallback(DeleteFile));

    return a;
}

public void DeleteFile(String key, object value,
    CacheItemRemovedReason removedReason)
{
    File.Delete(key);
}
```

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7kxdx246(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This works great!  Thank you!  As a side note, (at least in my case) it's unnecessary to put the file itself into the cache; I just put the filename into the key *and* value fields and the callback handles the rest.

Comment: Excellent to hear!  Depending on your platform, you might want to test this and make sure it still works under heavy load, if that is a valid use case.