# Two different expirations dates for twilio audio files

Tags: asp.net, parsing, iis, iis-7, twilio

I have an that uses Twilio and this app has 2 very different sets of audio files:

1. Menus (files never change)
2. Information (files change constantly)

At the moment I had to set all the cache for my files of as I couldn't figure out how to set a different expiration date before send the file to twilio, the problem been that twilio download the files directly from the website, so as far I as understand I cannot set the cache using ASP.net

I am using the xml below in the web.config in the directory where my files are at the moment but I cannot find a way to specify different values to different files, for example:

- menu1.wav - max cache
- meny2.wav - max cache
- info1.wav - no cache
- info2.wav - no cache

Is it even possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
          <staticContent>
              <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
          </staticContent>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Looks like you can use the `<location>` element to define different folders that have different cache policys on them:

[How to configure static content cache per folder and extension in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this approach as it will require a lot of changes in the code,  I am trying to find a way where I can set the cache  for the file as it is requested like I can do for the normal pages.