# How to solve Leverage browser caching in wordpress without using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I have a website made with WordPress and Windows Plesk panel hosting. Most of these type of hosting do not support htaccess due to IIS.

I want to solve Leverage browser caching in wordpress without using htaccess file.

I have tried below non htaccess caching thing but the site is displaying blank screen.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['img'])) {$filename = $_GET['img'];}else{exit;}
$allowed = array('gif','png','jpg');
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed)) {exit;}
$stc = 31536000;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $stc) . " GMT";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$stc, public");
header("Pragma: cache");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: IIS works with web.config files, rather than .htaccess

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the  Leverage browser caching, I did not find any web.config file in my host folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7 I havent used IIS for a long time, so i cant be more specific. If in doubt why not ask your host?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do below things to achieve A Grade in Gtmetrix by doing the below things.

some hosting provider do not like htaccess and therefore I preferred go for Hyper Cache plugins, and do all necessary configurations.

Then Add below things in header.php of your Wordpress themes.

```
<?php

$stc = 31536000;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $stc) . " GMT";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$stc, public");
header("Pragma: cache");
ob_clean();
flush();
exit;
?>
```

After check and do let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Its helps me to achieve A grade in GTmetrix and thank you for this, but could you please do let me know whats the use of . basename($filename) here ?