# Page Caching for certain URL Pattern on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, caching, c#-4.0, iis-8.5

Is there any way to implement Page Caching for some certain URL pattern? For example, I have articles on my ASP.NET website and they don't changed so frequently. All of them have a URL pattern as following:

> www.myite.com/articles/article1.aspx
>
> www.myite.com/articles/article2.aspx
>
> www.myite.com/articles/article3.aspx

and so on.

I want them all to be cached for 24 hours at least on server. How do I do it? Any help.

Comment: You can use Output Cache in your aspx page

Comment: thank you for your reply. I want to do it on for some URL patterns however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you should have a look into **Output Caching**. This feature can help you achieve caching of pages and display content for less frequently changing pages.

Some good links on Output Caching :

[MSDN : Output Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sfw2210t(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Output Caching Information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49704/ASP-NET-Page-Output-Cache)

Also, for caching the pages that follow a specific URL pattern, you can either do that individually(which is quite obvious) and you can have a look into the `<location>` attribute available in the web.config which can help you configure various settings for specific directory that you specify in it. Of course, cache settings are also available inside the child tags for this tag.

This link might point in the right direction :

[Set cache to a folder in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @matt... seems the right pointer. Will be back shortly to mark that as an answer.

Comment: @Sunny - No probs brother. Here to help. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: @SunnySharma: Did you implemented it? I also have same situation. I have more than 30 pages, and same url pattern. I don't want to cache each page indivually.

Comment: @AmitKumar I did it by separating contents into Master/Child forms and applied Output Cache inside Master Page's certain ContentPlaceHolders.