# Leverage browser caching : not able to set <location> attribute in web.config file

Tags: caching, web-config, browser-cache

For browser caching, I want to set expiration time for only one of my .js file in web.config not the whole js folder. For that I tried using the below configuration with the help of [How to configure static content cache per folder and extension in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7) but it doesn't work:

```
    <configuration>
     <location path="compiled.js">
       <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
       </system.webServer>
     </location>
  </configuration>
```

Then I tried to change the path in "location" attribute as shown below but this also doesn't work for me:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="~/js/compiled.js">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
  </configuration>
```

Can someone help me how do I set cache expiration time for only one .js file instead of whole folder via web.config?

Comment: If your answer resolves the issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single file we can set caching expiration time in web.config file as shown below:

```
    <configuration>
    <location path="js/compiled.js">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    </configuration>
```

Also, we can specify the cache settings for different files/folders by using different `<location>` sections.