# Cache busting static files(images, pdf's, png etc.) in assets folder for angular application?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, browser-cache, angular7

Our application is developed using angular-cli (version: 7.0.2) & angular (version: 7.0.0).
We have few image files, pdf's maintained in assets folder. These files change for every version of the app which releases every 3 months.

- What is the best way to achieve cache busting for all the files in assets folder?
- Is there a common technique which can be added to client app to load the latest of all files in assets folder whenever accessed? Is there any configuration which can be added in webpack.config.js (the file which gets generated when the project is created with angular-cli tool)?

I read through various techniques mentioned in this link: [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)

Not sure which is the best solution. Any suggestions / code snippets on how to implement cache busting is appreciated.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitelintcode/angular-static-assets-hash

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to achieve cache busting for all the files in
>   assets folder?

CDN || Server Cache

I think best way you can use hash name on your files, this way may change the current code.(image/file load path)

https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

> Is there a common technique which can be added to client app to load
>   the latest of all files in assets folder whenever accessed? Is there
>   any configuration which can be added in webpack.config.js (the file
>   which gets generated when the project is created with angular-cli
>   tool)?

I think [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) will help u.

If someone else have better solution ,i am interested in this problem too.

Comment: do you have a working example using file-loader? Because the image files are not getting loaded in production mode..

Comment: I ended up with configuring files in web.config [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7?noredirect=1&lq=1)