# Flash Caching Issue

Tags: flash, caching

I have a page that contains a flash object.  The flash file is wrong I a change was made to one of the images specified.  I have a big problem, users who have already hit the site, seem to have this flash object cached.  I have tried renaming it, have put in `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`, but no matter what I do, it still seems to recognize the cached flash object as being the object to display.  Try it in a new browser and it works fine.  Now I know I can clear the cache to get it work but I can't expect to tell every user this.  Any ideas as to what else I can try?

```html
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540001"
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0"
        width="1127" height="333" id="lottery6" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="wmode"  value="transparent" />
    <param name="movie"
           value="flashtemp/lottery1.swf?logo=<%=WinnerSponsorImage%>&winningNumber=<%=Winner%>&link=<%=WinnerSponsorLink%>&sponsorName=<%=WinnerSponsorName%>&winnerName=<%=WinnerName%>&hourToPlay=<%=PrizeDrawHr%>&minToPlay=<%=PrizeDrawMin%>" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#5d8804" />
    <embed wmode="transparent" quality="high" bgcolor="#5d8804"
           width="1127" height="333"
           name="lottery6" align="middle"
           allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false"
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
          src="flashtemp/lottery1.swf?logo=<%=WinnerSponsorImage%>&winningNumber=<%=Winner%>&link=<%=WinnerSponsorLink%>&sponsorName=<%=WinnerSponsorName%>&winnerName=<%=WinnerName%>&hourToPlay=<%=PrizeDrawHr%>&minToPlay=<%=PrizeDrawMin%>"  />
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the browser is caching the index page. Try adding the following meta tags in the `<head>` section of your html.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
```

If you're running Apache you can set the cache-related response headers in `.htaccess` (assuming `.htaccess` override is enabled in Apache's config). Example use of `.htaccess`...

```
<FilesMatch "^index\.html$">
Header set Cache-Control: "no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

More on this - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html

Edit: If you're running IIS you can set the cache control headers by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865252/add-expires-or-cache-control-header-to-static-content-in-iis) - [Add Expires or Cache Control Header to static content in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865252/add-expires-or-cache-control-header-to-static-content-in-iis)

Comment: Apologies, I should of mentioned that I am running .net.  I've put the meta tags in but it still appears to be loading the flash object from cache.  Which has baffled me!

Comment: @user1367729 are you running IIS? If so, you can set the cache-control headers for the swf and html file by... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865252/add-expires-or-cache-control-header-to-static-content-in-iis

Comment: will that stop the cookie from caching?