# How to convince browser to load images from cache rather than get from server

Tags: jquery, css, caching, iis, image-caching

i am using [Quake Slider](http://codevisually.com/quake-slider-jquery-imagecontent-slider-plugin/) in part of my website.this plugin is creating `div(s)` from images for making transition.the problem is when `div(s)` get created , `background-image` property of them changing according to current image `src` attribute, and causing the browser to reload image from the server (and strangely not from cache).can anyone give me the point how to change this plugin to not reload image when jquery `css('background-image')` get called?thanks for your concern.

Comment: What are expiration and caching headers sent from the server? Check response.

Comment: `Expires Thu Jan 01 1970 03:30:00 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)`

Comment: Exactly. All your images are sent with expiration in the past so they **must** be reloaded from the server. Try searching information how to configure your web server to send expired images.

Comment: Which web server are you using? Apache? IIS?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23365/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-robert-koritnik)

Comment: I've added an answer with a link that may be helpful. And due to security I'm unable to go to chat at the moment. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks.you gave me the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Expiration and caching response headers

Browsers reload content based on their last accessed expiration and caching headers sent from the web server. So if images expired in the past, browser will have to reload them regardless of whether they've just been loaded.

As you're using IIS I suggest you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/865252/75642) that links to MS resource with description of configuration elements to control this behaviour.

When you configure your server to not expire static content you can still convince browser to reload some static content by adding a random value along with your request i.e.

```
http://somewhere.com/images/always-realod.jpg?a9s87h7sdf6
```